# Лексический и синтаксический анализ TCL

Tags: парсер, компилятор

В рамках курсовой работы мне требуется написать компилятор для TCL. Если я правильно понимаю, грамматика этого языка контекстно-зависимая, а не контекстно-свободная. Писать нужно именно компилятор под LLVM, а не интерпретатор, поэтому нужен полноценный вывод.

Вопрос следующий. Есть ли какие-то подходящие, рабочие библиотеки лексического/синтаксического разбора для таких языков?

Comment: Lex + Yacc, bison не подойдут?

Comment: Не уверен, что я прав на 100%. Но вроде эта связка работает только с контекстно-свободными языками. А для TCL BNF согласно вики нет.

Comment: Давно не писал на tcl, но насколько помню его синтексис тривиален. В чем проблема странслировать "руками" (т.е. просто рекурсивным вызовом нескольких функций)?

Comment: Если вы собираетесь писать _компилятор_, то парсинг — наименьшая из проблем. Тем более, там синтаксис вроде несложный, можно и вручную попробовать. А где написано, что грамматика контекстно-зависимая?

Comment: http://itc.ua/articles/drevnyaya_novaya_budushhaya_prodolzhenie_16346/ Если имеется ввиду "рекурсивный парсинг", то, как я понял из книги дракона, он тоже только под КС языки. Можно, конечно, попробовать набыдлокодить. Но интересует сущестование каких-то "академических" способов.

Comment: Странно, что википедия (ни русская, и английская) не упоминает об этом неожиданном факте. PS: Хотя вот есть упоминание: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1643

Comment: И там же есть ссылка на готовый официальный парсер: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1660 Это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Официальный парсер не подойдет под требование курсовой. Можно использовать какие-то библиотеки, но не готовые парсеры.

Comment: Ничего себе у Вас курсовые (а я уж грешным делом хотел предложить использовать (ну, для начала, просто почитать) сами исходники tcl). / Интересно, а где Вы учитесь и что должно получиться в результате курсовой -- работающий в LLVM код? / (Если будете отвечать, то вбейте мой ник (@avp) для нотификации, а то тут теперь с этим как-то туго)

Comment: @avp Бауманка. иу7. Да, код в llvm.

Comment: Здорово! / Остается только порадоваться, что у нас стали так серьезно учить (особенно если преподаватель сам может сделать такой курсач -)). / А исходники, мне кажется, посмотреть в любом случае будет только полезно.

Comment: @avp Радоваться не стоит. Большинство преподов ничего не понимает) Но по компиляторам - да, очень толковый препод.